# vb6, variable not defined for Label using Module

Tags: vb6, module

Sorry to ask such a dumb question.. but for the life of me i cant get it.. i have searched EVERYWHERE... This is a Re-Creation of my code that gives the same error. This is the most basic example i could re-create.

I dont understand why i have to declare a Label ?? (or an object)

What I am trying to accomplish is use my main form to call all the modules.

This is the FORM

```
'frmMain.frm
Option Explicit

Public Sub btnOpen_Click()
    GetNum
End Sub
```

This is the MODULE

```
'modGet.bas
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetNum()
    Dim a As String
    Dim b As String

    a = "hello"
    b = "world"
->  Label1.Caption = a    'ERROR, Compile Error, Variable not Defined. (vb6)
    Label2.Caption = b
End Sub
```

YES, i have a form, with a Button named 'btnOpen', i have 2 Labels named 'Label1' & 'Label2'

If i ADD..

```
Dim Label1 As Object  'in MODULE
```

i get a different error..
ERROR '91' Object Variable or With block variable not set

IF I put everything in 1 FORM, it works..(but i want to use separate modules)
I Commented out 'OPTION EXPLICIT' ... same error.

In another Test, i got the error for a TextBox..

```
TextBox1.Text = x
```

Once i get the answer for this, i can apply it for everything... I'm sure it's simple too and imma feel stupid. :-(

One of my Main Things is Querying WMI, and i get the ERROR '91' for the Label (This is in a For Each Loop) .. But its the same error, its like its makin me Declare Objects..(using Modules)

```
Label1.Caption = objItem.Antecedent
```

If Someone Could PLEASE Help me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
form1.label1.caption = a
```

But make sure form1 is loaded

Comment: Thank You..Thank You... THATS what i was looking for... because i have MULTIPLE
textBoxes/Labels that Return Values to Form...
I have seen that in samples, but never had to use it.
NOW I know what it is...

it's " FormName.ControlName.Value = Var " when referencing...

Answer (score 4):

You get the error because Label1 and Label2, and your other controls for that matter do not exist in the scope of modGet.bas. They can only be referenced (the properties accessed or set), from with the form. The different error you get when you add `Dim Label1 As Object` is caused because an you defined Label1 as an Object, not as a Label, and an object does not have a Caption property. Unless you have a good reason for putting the GetNum sub in a .bas module move it into the form and it should work.

I modified the second example. It will modify the strings passed into it in a way that when execution passes back to the form you can assign the strings to your textboxes. I am against modifying controls on a form from another module because it goes against the idea of [encapsulation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/149041/82908).

```
'modGet.bas
Option Explicit

Public Function GetHello() As String
    Dim strHello As String

    strHello = "Hello"
    GetHello = strHello

End Function

'frmMain.frm
'Option Explicit

Public Sub btnOpen_Click()
    Label1.Caption = GetHello()
End Sub
```

Something a little different.

```
'MyModule.bas
Public Sub HelloWorld ByRef Value1 As String, ByVal Value2 As String)

    On Error GoTo errHelloWorld

    Value1 = "Hello"
    Value2 = "World"

    Exit Sub

errHelloWorld:
    ' deal with the error here

End Sub

'frmMain.frm
Option Explicit

Private Sub frmMain_Load()
    Dim strText1 As String
    Dim strText2 As String

    HelloWorld(strText1, strText2)
    Text1.Text = strText1
    Text2.Text = strText2
End Sub
```

I also added basic error handling in the second example

Comment: Thanks for the response.. but yes i know if i move it all into the form it works, that is not the real code, but its the same idea... but the project i am making has ALOT of subs & functions.. and i want to use MODULES and break it down some, so i need help.. i need to know HOW using the above code CAN i make it work ?? i dont want 1 form with 4,000 lines of code... i need to see an example of how to reference a object, textbox and/or label from within a module... THAT is what i NEED help with... (PLEASE)... Could someone show me a sample using above code to make it work ??

Comment: i guess what i am asking is...
Could someone show me HOW to..

1.) call a 'Hello World' module from a form...
2.) have the module return a value from a variable...
3.) and return the value to a txtBox or Label..

My main form will call a module, and run a sub or function
take that result and populate a txtBox or Label, then goto next
function and do the same.. but my problem is communicating between
form and module.

if i declare a variable on the form, i get an error using it on module
and vice-versa, there is something i am missing here.. if i learn this, i can apply it to MANY things.. thx